# Getting Menu Parameters from Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to get parameters from the menu table in Joomla. What I have below is working in the sense that it is returning the parameters.

```
 $menu =   &JSite::getMenu();
 $item =  $menu->getItem($menuId)->params;
 print $items;
```

However, It's returning them in plain text, as if I had just queried the column and returned the params contents.

Can someone tell me how to return this as an Object or Array so that I can use something like:

```
$myParam = $item->getParams('theParamIwant');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the JParameter class to read the params. Try something like this:

```
$item = $menu->getItem($menuId);
$params = new JParameter($item->params);
$myParam = $params->get('theParamIwant');
```

Comment: This was the correct anwser when it was written, but starting at some Joomla 2.5 patch, JParameter class was deprecated. Instead of JParameter class use JRegistry class in the same way: $params = new JRegistry($item->params);

Answer (score 16):

I think JParameter is obsolete in Joomla! 3.x, so the answer now is something like:

```php
 $app = JFactory::getApplication();
 $menuitem   = $app->getMenu()->getActive(); // get the active item
 $menuitem   = $app->getMenu()->getItem($theid); // or get item by ID
 $params = $menuitem->params; // get the params
 print_r($params); // print all params as overview
```

You can get the `menu_image` variable by doing:

```php
 echo $params->get('menu_image');
```

Or first check if it's filled in and, if it is, `echo` it:

```php
// using get() with a second parameter makes it fall back to this if nothing is found
$menu_image = $params->get('menu_image', false);
if ($menu_image && strlen($menu_image)) {
   echo "<img src='$menu_image'/>";
}
```

Or, using a `tertiary` operator:

```php
$menuimg = $params->get('menu_image')
echo strlen($menuimg) ? "<img src='$menuimg'/>" : '';
```

Comment: Regarding `if ($menu_image && strlen($menu_image) {` ...`strlen($menu_image)` is a redundant check; the first truthy check will do the job.  You also need a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work

Try to use this:

```
$params = $menus->getParams($menuId);
$myParam = $params->get('theParamIwant');
```

Comment: For which Joomla version is this? Looks like an old one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getParams();
$yourParameter = $params->get('YOURPARAMETERNAME');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ($currentMenuId = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ; // `enter code here`
    $document =& JFactory::getDocument(); // `enter code here`
    $app = JFactory::getApplication(); // `enter code here`
    $menuitem   = $app->getMenu()->getItem($currentMenuId); // or get item by ID `enter code here`
    $params = $menuitem->params; // get the params `enter code here`
    $params->get('menu-meta_keywords');
    if($document->description == '') // 116 is the ID number of the menu pointing to the component `enter code here`
    {
    $this->setMetaData( 'description', $params->get('menu-meta_description') );
    $this->setMetaData( 'keywords', $params->get('menu-meta_keywords') );
    }
    else
    {
    // do nothing
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Working in 3.5.1

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$currentMenuId = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id;
$menuitem   = $app->getMenu()->getItem($currentMenuId);
$params = $menuitem->params;
echo $params['menu_image'];
```

Shows menu item image

Answer (score -1):

JParameter is deprecated in Joomla 2.5, so to get Kevin's code to work add

`jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter' )` before i.e

```
jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter' );
$item = $menu->getItem($menuId);
$params = new JParameter($item->params);
$myParam = $params->get('theParamIwant');
```

Comment: This is not a real solution, more of a hack to re-include a deprecated class and function ;)